# Valid regular expression for identifier using flex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to make a regular expression that will only work when a valid identifier name is given, using flex (the name cannot start with a number). I'm using this code :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

%}

%%
"if"                        { printf("IF "); }
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*      { printf("%s ", yytext); }

%%

int main() {
    yylex();
}
```

but it is not working. how to make sure that flex accepts only a valid identifier?

When I provide the input:

```
if
abc
9abc
```

I see the following output:

```
IF
abc
9abc
```

but I expected:

```
IF
abc
(nothing)
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Please specify an input which produces an unexpected result, as well as the result produced and your expectations.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, i've edited the post

Answer (score 3):

Your patterns do not match all possible inputs.

In such cases, (f)lex adds a default catch-all rule, of the form

```
.|\n   { ECHO; }
```

In other words, any character not recognized by your patterns will simply be printed on `stdout`. That will be the case with the newline characters in your input, as well as with the digit <kbd>9</kbd>. After the <kbd>9</kbd> is recognized by the default rule, the remaining input will again be recognized by your identifier rule.

So you probably wanted something like this:

```
%option warn nodefault
%%
[[:space:]]+                ; /* Ignore whitespace */
"if"                        { /* TODO: Handle an "if" token */ }
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*   { /* TODO: Handle an identifier token */ }
.                           { /* TODO: Handle an error */ }
```

Instead of printing information to `stdout` in an action as a debugging or learning aid, I strongly suggest you use the [`-T` (or `--trace`) option](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Debugging-Options.html) when you are building your scanner. That will automatically output debugging information in a consistent and complete manner; it would have told you that the default rule was being matched, for example.

#### Notes:

1. `%option nodefault` tells flex not to insert a default rule. I recommend always using it, because it will keep you out of trouble. The `warn` option ensures that a warning is issued in this case; I think that `warn` is default flex behaviour but [the manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Scanner-Options.html) suggests using it and it cannot hurt.
2. It's good style to use standard character class expressions. Inside a character class (`[`…`]`), `[:xxx:]` matches anything for which the standard library function `isxxx` would return true. So `[[:space:]]+` matches one or more whitespace characters, including space, tab, and newline (and some others), `[[:alpha:]_]` matches any letter or an underscore, and `[[:alnum:]_]*` matches any number (including 0) of letters, digits, or underscores. See the [Patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) section of the manual.